# Помогите пожалуйста выровнять 1ю строку в таблице умножения

Tags: c, выравнивание, таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char* argv)
    {
        puts("   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ");
        puts("-------------------------------------");
    
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++)
            {
                if (y < x)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (y < 10)
                    {
                        printf("%4d",x*y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%6d",x*y);
                    }
                }
            }
            puts("");
        }
         puts("-------------------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: Какая-то у вас странная таблица... она таки должна быть треугольной? Что именно вы хотите получить? дайте какой-то набросок, к чему надо стремиться :)

Comment: Набросок добавила)

Comment: Очень нужна подсказка

Comment: задайте вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам. Я вижу на рисунке ровную таблицу. В чем проблема?

Comment: рисунок это то как должно выглядеть, если вставить в компайлер мой код, то первая строка сдвинута, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите, что у Вас получается, чтобы было понятно, что искать... Сделайте скрин вывода программы и приложите к вопросу.

Comment: Странно. У меня дает совсем другой вывод. Но у меня другая среда разработки.  И у меня получался сдвиг всех строк, кроме первой, влево. Пришлось ```printf(" ");``` заменить на ```printf("    ");```, т.е. поставить в кавычках 4 пробела

Comment: Кстати, вывод дан не того кода, что приведен в вопросе. Что Вы изменили?

Comment: я уже видел этот код. и даже эти скриншоты. Скорее всего там в кавычках не просто пробелы, а табуляция спряталась. Вот оно и разлезлось.

Comment: @KoVadim Забавно, о таком варианте даже мысли не было... а похоже.

Comment: поменяйте `printf(" ");` в котором табуляция, на четыре пробела `printf("    ");` Причина в том,что в разных системах табуляция с разным количеством.

Comment: поменяйте `printf(" ");` в котором табуляция, на четыре пробела `printf("    ");` Причина в том,что в разных системах табуляция с разным количеством.

Answer (score 1):

Так устроит?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ");
    puts("-------------------------------------");

    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (x-1)*4; ++i) printf(" ");

        for (int y = x; y <= 9; y++)
        {
            printf("%4d",x*y);
        }
        puts("");
    }
     puts("-------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: В онлайн компайлере правильно, а в dev c++  совсем не так

Comment: Видимо, проблема в среде разработки, а не в коде.

Comment: А как в вашей среде?

Comment: @Harry У меня выводится корректно.

Answer (score 1):

поменяйте `printf(" ");` в котором табуляция, на четыре пробела `printf("    ");` Причина в том,что в разных системах табуляция с разным количеством.

У вас она оказалась в восемью пробелами.

Comment: @bladerunner201 И для табуляции используйте `\t`...